# itextsharp - Problems reading PDFs with 1 column (page1) and 2 columns (page2)

Tags: itext

My code below is lost when opening PDF file which has only one column on the front page and more than 1 column on other pages.

Someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Below my code:

```
PdfReader pdfreader = new PdfReader(pathNmArq);
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

    for (int page=1; page <= lastPage; page++) 
    {
         extractText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfreader, page, strategy);
         extractText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extractText)));
        / / ... 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy`. This strategy assumes that the text drawing instructions in the PDF are sorted by the reading order. In your case that does not seem to be the case.

If you cannot count on the PDF containing drawing operations in reading order but are only using iText text extraction strategies from the distribution, you have to know areas which constitute a single column. If a page contains multiple columns, you have to use `RegionTextRenderFilter` to restrict to a column and then use the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`.

**PS:** What exactly is your intention in that

```
extractText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(extractText)));
```

line?

Comment: The code "Encoding.UTF8 ..." was extracted from an example. 
In my case I only need to read PDFs that may have alternate amounts of columns. I saw this code works well for fixed amount of columns but works wrong if you have variations. 


Not very well iTextSharp domain coding, if you can help me I appreciate it.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, *you have to know areas which constitute a single column.* Do you?

Comment: Yes, as I know what is the PDF to be read, I know the size of each column (1,2 or 3) ... I just do not know where the page will appear with 1, 2 or 3 columns within the PDF. 

How should I proceed?

Comment: If the pdf does not provide information like that, you'll have to find out which page has how many columns.

Comment: OK, but how I can do this? 
Will I need open page by page and see how many columns have, but how?

Comment: *Will I need open page by page and see how many columns have* - If your documents do not provide the information and you do not want to program image analysis, yes.